# my php codeigniter project is not work in linux but work in windows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem with CodeIgniter PHP 
it works with windows server
when I move  it  to Linux Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't work
and i set all requirement  of codeigniter in Linux Ubuntu 18.04

this in Linux Ubuntu 18.04

PHP version = 5.6

and  I'm trying to install 3 versions of PHP 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 but still have the same problem 
could you please advise me what I have to do

the Erorr is show like this 
the error is showing like this>>>

> J½÷Ö?z>^©6sªÿ}ˆ”Éö™º,¼éJ›ÍÆËˆ/“%ÄCÛÕÈIÌdãCïŠº:ÄM>ëQTËoÜºþèÓìío]ã‚Î—J¥ŸþŸ4ç|1b]’If·ìæÈž½ÏõxV/êˆKSÏ
>   †Ñ:°LŒpflß²¿ª©ïšºo^)L-¢9z_of×6¦}÷íF¡fª}nsiã39>EM@ˆÐ·œž9ãm
>
> ## BŒ—óè‰ þ”AGr“ðOØs«~Z ßÚEŸ‰Õs-I°Çc¨Ÿíu2Ð ÷MÆHN¨<ón*%^˜avÿTp1ÔÎêøásàŠÞò
>
> /O¾¸MPØM—-BüEçDÓ¶F³ç¸ú—¹Vnc“^_Y86´©¯–Òm¥£¼%²0ÛÚ?Ý=*¿Ùþgöogmù8€VÚŽ;‹ññxÙà•wõÛ\,þë~¹qS®'VÊý`µ>n-ŽàoÉ:K÷Ê@ª@w²ËG½÷(0^µóÉW7ÆÂ1¼!éÀÆ)¨ø}Ÿ…˜á—IR¤8~W¿ñ%=ÒÐâRý:ó—W,£;Ö–2x.n7wõ=×Žç­qê7Ê2,¡‹ãk5¬¡èVÁDúUø2ÓúÞPyXúþuÉkŠàjâœF`7I`dU®ö«;Óº»*¸ÿé«ÓÇnâj¿S^RGù®êÆ$>á©6ádˆœå"[»´FÆ–_x‘>ŽuÙ¢Éœš´çØÐÏãÅ¡š_x%žÚfÌ
>   WU«?™ŸÕo;w»øqKPÛ“""³åß±šðu»Åd~/zkÌ®
>   ÒÙNVæUÂ´?åÈ‘Ã³Í’¦ÁØ‡ºrüÛr¿ë‡£z·|Qºd]wY¨KÜåOµÜ÷õF‹È Ãà“á/Fþ÷ß6§
>   o®ØuX2:Ùõ>V˜NÏ*aïºÔï8¤¸Ž±¡ªO6Ü±¹çŠ _íæ:¹É

Comment: Somehow, I don't see you error. It's written in weird letters.

Comment: that is my problem

Comment: Maybe the file encoding is some windows encoding the Linux machine does not know? Try converting everything to UTF8.

Comment: I solved it work now because Linux is case-sensitive so I change the name of classes into uppercase and it works with me